# Need to index an array from part of each array value

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have a data file, with each line containing tab-separated values. I want to take the first value (an ID), and index the $lines array (created with the file() function) with those values. I seem to have to do this in two steps.

```
$lines = file( '/_info.dat', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );
$myKeys =  array_map( "strpop", $lines); 
//strpop is a function that puts the first value in an array
$myInfo =  array_combine( $myKeys, $lines);
```

This is strpop()

```
 function strpop( $line ) {
        $id = strstr( $line, "\t", true );
        if ( !empty( $id ) ) {
            $array = $id;
        }
        return $array;
    }
```

I have another function, but it creates an array of arrays...

```
function strpopLine( $line ) {
    $array = array();
    $id = strstr( $line, "\t", true );
    if ( !empty( $id ) ) {
        $array[ $id ] = $line;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Like so:

```
array(949) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [1477240993]=>
    string(257) "1477240993 APPLIANCE SALE  005 at Brown’s Appliances...etc 
}
```

Instead of

```
array(949) { [1477240993]=>
  string(257) "1477240993   APPLIANCE SALE  005 at Brown’s Appliances...etc 
}
```

Comment: Please see that this page is not abandoned.  Please progress this page to a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely don't want to parse each of the csv lines (keep them as tab-delimited strings) you can use this:

```
$result = [];
foreach (file( '/_info.dat', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) as $line) {
    $id = strstr($line, "\t", true);
    if ($id !== false) {
        $result[$id] = $line;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Otherwise, parse it. Something like this:

```
$fp = fopen('/_info.dat', 'r');
while(($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
    $result[$line[0]] = $line;
    // [1477240993 => [1477240993, 'APPLIANCE SALE', '005 at Brown’s Appliances', ...]]
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with fgetcsv. Will study that. My issue is that  when I use my code as a function for array_map, I get an array of one value arrays, not a one-dimensional array of key => values. But I appreciate the input! I will also try using $id !== false

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue. https://3v4l.org/3g658  Something else is creating the extra array level.

Comment: Thank you. I had to fall back to an earlier workflow, and will continue experimenting.

Comment: Please ensure that this page is progressed to a system-recognized resolution (not abandoned).